# Mounting USB in android 4.1.2

Tags: usb, android-emulator, shell, usb-on-the-go, scripts

I am trying to mount USB pen drive in my old Xperia phone running Android 4.1.2 When I connect OTG device to my phone I get an USB power consumption error.

After little search I found a command to make it work.

```
su
echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/bConfigurationValue
```

When I execute this command from Terminal Emulator it works perfectly and USB drive is detected by my phone.

To avoid typing this command I am trying to created a Shell script which will run this command automatically using SManager:

[image: Shell Script] [image: SManager Config]
<sup>Shell script (left) and SManager Config (right; click images for larger variants)</sup>

When checked the log file i got only one line: `script started`

SManager executes it as:

```
# /system/bin/sh /storage/sdcard0/myusb.sh
```

I am not able to find out where I am going wrong. Need help!

Comment: I'd have the script log something to see if it is really executed (successfully). Include e.g. `echo "Script started" >> /sdcard/myusb.log` before the `su` command, and `echo "Return code is $?" >> /sdcard/myusb.log` at the very end, followed a `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/bConfigurationValue`. Then you can evaluate the log to see whether a) the script was executed at all, b) the command succeeded, and c) the value was set.

Comment: @Izzy: I have followed your instructions and updated the script. It gets stuck at the su command itself. Not sure whats wrong. I have updated the question to include the changes. Please have a look.

Comment: Any popup from the SuperUser app? Does SManager support root executions? If so, can you directly advice it to have the script run as root (so you wouldn't neet the extra `su` in the script itself)?

Comment: @Izzy: there is this SU option in the second screenshot. Maybe I will have to dig in more. I will let you know by evening. :)

Comment: Sure. Other than on the shell, apps must explicitly support root – and register with the SuperUser/SuperSU app installed. AFAIK you cannot simply run a script calling "su". SManager seems to support this (by the screenshot). I'd say you need to activate the "Su" option there, and kick it out of the script – then it should work.

Comment: How much current is your USB pen drive trying to draw?  It's visible under `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/bMaxPower`